# Значення слова “активувати”

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова

Досить часто у сучасному житті нас просять що-небудь активувати, наприклад: куплену [SIM-карту](https://kyivstar.ua/uk/support/mobile_connection/sim_and_number/yak-aktyvuvaty-sim-kartu-kyyivstar) мобільного оператора, або [бонусну картку](https://varus.ua/uk/varus-perfect) продуктового гіпермаркета, подарункові [сертифікати](https://giftmall.com.ua/uk/activation) і навіть [програмне забезпечення](https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/15083/windows-how-to-activate). Але що саме означає данний термін?

Дієслово явно похідне від іменника "активація".

СУМ-11 [тлумачить](http://sum.in.ua/s/aktyvacija) вказаний термін у такий спосіб:

> **АКТИВА́ЦІЯ**, ї, жін., спец. Перехід з недіяльного стану в діяльний; посилення діяльного стану. *Біогенні стимулятори, будучи добавлені до ферментів рослинного походження, викликають їх активацію (Фізіологічний журнал, II, 3, 1956, 26)*.

Вікісловник [наводить](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) такі ж значення, як і [Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53392/822885.html).

Вікіпедія [трактує](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) значення слова трохи по іншому:

> **Актива́ція** — збудження чогось, наприклад, молекул, атомів; перехід молекули з неактивного стану в стан з енергією, достатньою для здійснення хімічної реакції, наприклад, механохімічна активація.

Отож, власне кажучи запитання: чи є правильним вживання данного слова в контексті, приміром наведених прикладів, слова "активувати"? І чи є якісь інші, пропущені значення цього слова?

Answer (score 4):

Так.

[СУМ‑20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=724&page=31)

> **АКТИВА́ЦІЯ**, **ї**, *ж., спец.*
>
> 1. Перехід з недіяльного стану в діяльний; посилення діяльного стану. *Біогенні стимулятори, додані до ферментів рослинного походження, викликають їх активацію* (з наук. літ.); *Лімбічна система є важливою ланкою регуляторної системи, що моделює рівень активації кори великих півкуль* (з наук. літ.); *Ці ліки сприяють активації клітинного імунітету* (із журн.).
> 2. Переведення чого-небудь у діючий, функціональний стан. *З метою безпеки отримана Вами кредитна картка неактивна, тобто перш ніж Ви зможете скористатися кредитним лімітом, необхідно здійснити її активацію* (з мови документів); *Для того щоб скористатися перевагами послуги “мультимедійні повідомлення” у вашому мобільному телефоні, вам потрібно здійснити її активацію через Інтернет* (з Інтернету); *Активація комп'ютерної програми.*
> 3. Обробка деревного вугілля або інших пористих тіл спеціальним розчином для збільшення їхньої здатності до поглинання рідин, газів. *Активація деревного вугілля.*

Answer (score 0):

Можна також побачити визначення слова "ативізація" (від якого і утворилося дієслово "активувати") на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/aktyvatsiia):

> **Актива́ція** — переходження з недіяльного стану в діяльний.

Тобто, коли ми активуємо SIM-карту, то ми змінюємо її стан (бо до цього вона не використовувалася, тобто була "[неактивна](http://sum.in.ua/s/neaktyvnyj)").

Однак, треба зазначити, що це слово має й інші значення, а також не варто плутати "активувати" та "активізувати". Про це йдеться в [Літературному слововживанні](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53392/29965.html):

> **Активізувати**, -ую, -уєш, недок. і док. Робити діяльнішим, активнішим когось, щось: активізувати дослідження, активізувати
>   зусилля, активізувати діяльність організму (серця), активізувати
>   життєдіяльні ферменти. Пох.: активізація, активізований (активізований
>   навчальний процес), активізуватися.
>
> **Активувати**, недок. і док. Збільшувати нагромадження енергії в організмі або речовині, посилювати діяльний стан: активувати молекули,
>   активувати ріст організму, активувати фізіологічні функції людини.
>   Пох.: активатор, активація, активований (активоване вугілля).